# ZF2 Setting up LDAP SSO

Tags: ldap, zend-framework2, single-sign-on

I'm creating a site that works in a network (with other sites) that share the same Active Directory to authenticate the users (SSO).

I've manage to authenticate my user...

```
    $auth = new \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService();

    $options = array(
        'server' => array(
            'host' => $host,
            'baseDn' => $dc
        ),
    );

    $adapter = new \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Ldap($options, $username, $password);
    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
```

... but I just dont get it how to check if the user is already auth'ed (from another site in the network) or what do i need to keep in session (or headers?) so that the others sites knows that the user is already logged in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there is already a provision for multiple-site SSO created by the organization you are working with, it would require something like oauth, which *wraps* their directory service and handles SSO in a browser-friendly way. I've seen SSO for web apps done non-oauth ways too, but it has always relied on the sites sharing a common root domain, and hence having shared cookie scope.

Bottom line: SSO between domains is not an in-built feature of Zend\Authentication or LDAP in general.

FWIW, I've built a custom Zend\Authentication adapter for a custom corporate SSO scheme before, and it's a snap. You just have to implement the very simple interface.

Also FWIW, if they *don't* already have SSO, we're currently implementing something similar, by building a custom oauth2 provider which wraps the customer's directory service. After weighing the options, we're going with https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php as the core library. (note: be careful what you are signing up for, as building and owning the oauth2 provider is non-trivial)